# How to use altgr-intl in KDE?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, kde, altgr

I'm using KDE 4.13.3 (on a Ubuntu 14.04) and I'd like to use the altgr-intl keyboard variant so that I can e.g. type <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>, then <kbd>e</kbd> to obtain `ê`.

Seemingly-relevant layouts displayed via *System Settings*, *Input Devices*, *Keyboard* include:

- Layout: English (US)

  Variant: English (US, international AltGr Unicode combining)
- Layout: English (US)

  Variant: English (US, international AltGr Unicode combining, alternative)

But none of them work as intended: when typing the accent combination, it is appended to the *current* letter, instead of waiting for me to type the *next* letter. So I have to type the letter *before* typing the accent, which is so unnatural that I cannot (and do not want to) get used to it.

How can I obtain the `altgr-intl` layout, that is, the "standard" behavior for this kind of "AltGr-dead keys"?

I even tried the *US, international with dead keys* variant, but it uses dead keys for every accent-related key, so typing `"` for instance requires a two-input combo: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>, then <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the layout I was looking for is **not** available from the KDE Control Module. I had naively assumed it contained all relevant layouts...

So far, the only way I could enable it was by using `setxkbmap` directly. Since I only needed to change the variant, the following command was sufficient:

```
setxkbmap -variant altgr-intl
```

Using `setxkbmap -query` can confirm it has been taken into account. It also shows that all other layouts correspond to different variants, and `altgr-intl` does not seem to be among them.

Note: Unfortunately, it still does not solve my issue with the euro sign, which <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> was supposed to produce.
I did enable (via the *Advanced* tab, *Configure keyboard options*, *Adding currency signs to certain keys*, *Euro on 5*) option `eurosign:5`, but it does not work.

But it didn't work either with the *US international with dead keys* layout that I was using before anyway, so it's not a loss. Using option *Position of Compose key*, *Right Alt* (`compose:ralt`), I can still use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, then <kbd>=</kbd>, or alternatively <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, then <kbd>=</kbd>, to obtain `€`.

Comment: For me, the `setxbmap` command was enough to alloe AltGr+5 to give a €.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are looking for the Compose Key. Unless it has been configured otherwise by the user, on Xorg the default, at least for English keyboards, appears to be <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>¹.

Note: That is not a simultaneous combination. You must press and release <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>, then press and release <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, then proceed with the corresponding key combination according to the glyph you're after.

For example:

<kbd>Right Shift</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> yields `ê`

<kbd>Right Shift</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd> yields `€`

<kbd>Right Shift</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> yields   (Non-breaking space)

<kbd>Right Shift</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> yields `☺` (Smiling face)

And so on and so forth.

A more exhaustive list, along with some information on how to reassign the Compose Key (which may or may not be accurate) can be found at http://fsymbols.com/keyboard/linux/compose/

In terms of reassigning your Compose Key (or figuring out where it is) at the X level, I refer you to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/200728). The location of the relevant KDE file depends on your particular KDE version and possibly distro, but it's likely to be either `~/.kde4/share/config/kxkbrc` or `~/.config/kxkbrc`.

Refer to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst` in your own machine for the list of modifier key mnemonics (you are looking for the third level modifier: `grep '^ *lv3:' /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst`)

Lastly, do note that it is possible that your keyboard responds to somewhat shorter key combinations, such as:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> for `ê`

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> for `€`

¹ Source: [http://www.amazon.com/Compose-Sequence-Reference-Guide-2012/dp/1468141104](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1468141104) (there used to be an online version but it's not longer accessible).

Answer (score 0):

I think is an ancient bug is not fixed yet, check this:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=295633